# Why bufferedreader.readLine() needs to equal to a temporary string while reading it?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, java-io

As following code snippet shown. While reading with `BufferedReader`, the `Buffereder.readLine()` is always set to a temporary string.

```
String hello = "hello ";
byte[] data = hello.getBytes();
ByteArrayInputStream bai = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bai))){
      String temp;

      while((temp=br.readLine())!=null)
         System.out.println(temp);

}catch(Exception exception){

}
```

Why can't we just do

```
while(br.readLine()!=null)
   System.out.println(br.readLine())
```

Comment: You can of course do that, so why don't you try? You'll soon realise why you *shouldn't*.

Comment: Every call to `readLine` advances the internal pointer to the next line. That loop would skip every other line of the file.

Comment: Because every call to `readLine()` returns a different value.

Comment: As per the Javadocs *Reads a line of text.* Call it twice == reads two lines of text

Comment: Because you need the temporary string, because that's where the `readLine()` result is. Otherwise you just throw it away.

Comment: Ok I got it know. Thanks guys who answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

If you do

```
while(br.readLine()!=null)
   System.out.println(br.readLine())
```

you will throw away every other line.  Think about it. Each time around the loop you do `readLine()` and test to see if it's not `null`.  OK, it's not, so you go into the loop and do **another** `readLine()`.  What happened to the line you read and tested to decide if you should go into the loop?

Comment: Thanks! I got it now!

Comment: @Johnny: don’t forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) answers.